# Badge over portrait, why no overflow? 2 Bitmaps inside a Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, sprite, loader

this is driving me nuts, so I guess it's time I ask for help.

The use case is simple:

We have several 50x64 portraits, and several 20x20 badges. And we want 1 badge to be randomly displayed on the bottom right corner of each portrait like so:

```
------
|    |  portrait (50x64)
|    |
|    |
|   ===
----=== <-- badge (20x20)
    ===

This is what we want
```

The display.Loader class is used to load all those pictures (so once loaded they probably become Bitmap internally).

In order to return something clean to the upper level, we create a containing Sprite, and then  we call sprite.addChild() to add the 2 loaders. See sample here:

```
var container = new Sprite();
...
container.addChild(loaderPortrait);
...
var loaderBadge = new Loader();      // some loading done in between
loaderBadge.x = 50 - 10;
loaderBadge.y = 64 - 10;
container.addChild(loaderBadge);
return container;
```

This almost works. The problem is the badge is cropped to the limits of the portrait. As if there was a mask. This phenomenon is known to happen when you would addChild() the badge to the portrait. But here bot are simply appended to the containing Sprite.

```
------
|    |  portrait (50x64)
|    |
|    |
|   ==
----== <-- badge (cut, 10x10 instead of 20x20)
This is what we get
```

Btw setting the badge to top-left instead of bottom-right, ie using an offset of (-10; -10), makes the badge overflow outside of the portrait, so no problem in that case.

```
=== <-- badge (20x20)
===----
===   |  portrait (50x64)
 |    |
 |    |
 |    |
 ------ 
It works if badge shown on top-left corner.
```

Any help to understand what's happening would be appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce the clipping you are referring to, putting two images inside a sprite works just fine. Here is the code http://pastebin.com/eGPvPqBE, maybe you have some masks that are applied or something else that is overlapping the badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. 
Vesper explanations on Sprite that should not behave like that, examplified by Barış Uşaklı comments, are correct.

The problem I had is that my portraits were organized on a grid. The badge was displayed, but overlapped by the neighbouring portraits.

```
|  |  |  |
| x|y |  |
----------
| y|y |  |
|  |  |  |
----------
```

On above's picture, the square with x and y represents a badge. The x was the visible portion of the badge, but all parts with y are overlapped by other portraits. This explains why the badge was shown on top-left but not on bottom-right (this would have been the contrary would have the children been added from right to left and bottom to top).

(Now I got to figure out how to make them badges show through, but it seems impossible without using another layer.)

Comment: Answering the last problem, in order to avoid re-architecturing things, changing the  **for (y=0; y<ySize; y++) for (x=0; x<xSize; x++) {... create portraits }**  to **for (y=ySize; y>0; y--) for (x=xSize; x>0; x--) { ... create portraits }** did the trick.

Comment: You can also spread your portraits a bit, so that if they take 50x64 with badges requesting additional 10 to both sides, you make your grid 60x74 instead, this will solve both problems at the cost of a little more space.

Answer (score -1):

Are you making the bitmap of this sprite of size 50x64?

It may be the reason for cropping the image

Comment: It shouldn't, as sprites are not dependant on contained bitmaps.

Comment: I traced the width and height of the returned Sprite ("container") after adding children, its width x height is 0x0. The parent is also 0x0.

Comment: trace the width height after completely loading the images.

you can get this with, ImgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoadComplete);

Comment: **However** the grandfather, for a reason I ignore, has a size of 50x64. I will inquiry to know how it got this size, but even though, as Vesper said, should it matter?

Comment: No, vesper is saying it correct, it should have no effect on a sprite.

Comment: And by "the grandfather", do you mean the parent of sprite?

Comment: @saurabh Tracing width and height should return correct dimensions only after you add the sprite to stage. Before that, you get zeroes or bogus data.

Comment: Bogus data after the COMPLETE event also? I wasn't aware of this, I always use the values COMPLETE event returns.